# Convert from json to array with knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have json file 'stars.json':

```
   {"person":
 [
      {
        "name": "a"
      },
      {
        "name": "b"
      },
      {
        "name": "c"
      },
      {
        "name": "d"
      }
    ]
}
```

then I would like to send data to kendo element:

```
 $('#grid').kendoDropDownList({
     autoWidth: false,
        filter: "startswith",
        value: self.valore,
        optionLabel: "Select value...",
        dataSource: {

        }
 });
```

What should I do in the datasource to convert json to simple array?
I would like to get something like this:

```
data=['a','b','c','d'];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simply array function to get the results what you required

Suppose

```
var data = {"person":
 [
      {
        "name": "a"
      },
      {
        "name": "b"
      },
      {
        "name": "c"
      },
      {
        "name": "d"
      }
    ]
}
```

then use the array map function like this

```
var newData = data.person.map(function(obj){
    return obj.name
});
console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering there's a variable `person` with value:

```
{"person":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"d"}]}
```

you can simply do:

`person.person.map((o)=> o.name)`